# Failed to open android emulator on remote machine using PsExec

Tags: android, android-emulator, psexec

I have `Android Emulator` and using `command line` i can open my `emulator` using this `command`:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_XL_API_27
```

Now i want to do the same but this time from another machine so i try to use this command:

```
C:\PsExec.exe -u domain\myUser -p myPassword \\192.168.1.2 -accepteula -h cmd /c C:\startAndroidEmulator.bat
```

This file `C:\startAndroidEmulator.bat` is locate to the emulator machine and works fine when executed (open the emulator).

This is the output of the `PsExec`:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe
>   -avd Pixel_XL_API_27 -gpu off SetProcessDpiAwareness(2) failed: COM error 0xffffffff80070005  (Unknown error 0x0ffffffff80070005), using 2
>   HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. audio: Failed to
>   create voice `goldfish_audio_in' qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning:
>   opening audio input failed audio: Failed to create voice`adc' audio:
>   Failed to create voice `adc' UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for
>   ptDst=(34, 0), size=(300x21), dirty=(300x21 0, 0) (A device attached
>   to the system is not functioning.)

And when this finish i can see on the `emulator` machine 2 running `services` called `emulator (32 bit)` and `emulator64-crash-service`